# Flutter provider not updating the UI

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm pretty sure I have everything setup correctly, or at least very close to correctly. However, either `notifyLister()`, my `consumer` is not working or maybe both.

I have my `UserModel` setup like so

```
...

class UserModel with ChangeNotifier {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> _user;

      Map get user {
        return _user;
      }

      void setUser(user) {
        _user = user;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }
```

I have my app setup like this in `main.dart`

```
...

void main() {
  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
    builder: (context) => UserModel(),
    child: MyApp()
  ),
  );
}
```

Next I have a button that calls the `setUser` method in the `UserModel`

```
...

UserModel().setUser(user);

...
```

Lastly I have a `Consumer` nested in a column in the build method of `app.dart`

```
....

Consumer<UserModel>(
    builder: (context, user, child) {
        return user.user == null ? Text(
            'NULL ${user.user}',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
        ) : Text(
            'NOT NULL ${user.user}',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
        );
    },
),

....
```

`user.user` is at first placed on the screen which is correct because starts out as `null` however, when the user logs in the `_user` in the model is set to its eventual value the UI does not update. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here you created new object ;

```
UserModel().setUser(user);
```

so you set the user in empty object you will never use it should be

```
Provider.of<UserModel>(context).setUser(user);
```